# Linker Script - RAM and ROM same Memory Space

Tags: c, compilation, linker, linker-errors

I try to link a binary. On my system the RAM and ROM address spaces are overlapping, but are on different busses (instruction bus vs data bus).

So my goal is to get two binary files. One with the ROM content (program) and one with the RAM content (.data section). I guess that the linker cannot generate these two files at once. My idea was to do two separate linker runs but the problem is that on the 'RAM run' for example it misses the .text section. Is there a more conveniant way to do this?

Here is my script for the second run:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )

/* initialize helper variables */
RAMSIZE = $RAMSIZE;
RAM_OFFSET = $RAMOFFSET;

MEMORY {
  ram (!rx) : ORIGIN = RAM_OFFSET, LENGTH = RAMSIZE /* size of Data Memory and offset */
}

SECTIONS {
  .sdata : { *(.sdata) } > ram              /* global/static variables */
}
```

I get following error:
    error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.text'

Comment: @tilz0R Several 8/16 bit MCU with tight address maps chose to place RAM and ROM at the same addresses out of reset. RAM usually takes precedence and you have to tweak some register if you wish to bring out the ROM from behind the RAM. As one example, NXP S12 family often works like this. And yes it is very annoying.

Comment: @tilz0R: That is my own implementation of a riscv-cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more conveniant way to do this?

I came to the solution that the linker generates first the program data. After that, it fills in the .data section. Both, the RAM and the ROM beginning with 0x0000. To avoid overlapping linker errors, I marked the .data section with the "ram AT rom tag". A script of mine post process this binary, separates these two parts and tag the bytes with programmer control and address data for the SoC internal programming module.